# Owl slider center with 3 images: one center - big, left and right smaller

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I use Owl slider and want to do slider like the below screen. How can I do it?

[image: Owl slider]

Answer (score 0):

Set `items: 3` in your owl options, then you can use `.active:first-of-type, .active:last-of-type` in your CSS to make the active items to the left and right smaller.